# Stat Symbolic Link : won't show original file modification time

Tags: symlink, stat

Stat Symbolic Link

```
stat file
```

it only shows data on when the symbolic link was created.

I was hoping to get data on when the origin had been modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stat` calls `lstat(2)` (by default) to get it's data. As the symlink occupies an inode in the filesystem, it gets the relevant data from that inode, which includes the modification time.

If you want to follow symlinks, `stat` has `-L` (`--dereference`) option, which uses `stat(2)` instead of `lstat(2)`:

```
stat -L file
```